# Open Ports and Network Config Needed For Home Sharing

Tags: network, home-sharing, remote.app

At work, I cannot get home sharing to work with the iOS Remote app to see my Macbook Pro's iTunes instance. Both the laptop and the iOS devices are connected to the same network (have tried both wi-fi and Ethernet for the laptop)

Going into the app, no devices show up and it says to enable home sharing.

Home sharing is enabled in iTunes and as soon as I go home and connect to my home network, I can see the MacBook Pro's iTunes install via home sharing.

So my question is what port(s) configuration would have to be done to make it show up at work? Our IT people said it's not an intentional blocking of the service and would like to help if we can figure out what ports need to be opened to make home sharing work.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203311) Apple support document the following ports have to be open:

Home Sharing uses TCP port 3689 and UDP port 5353 to communicate with shared iTunes libraries.

Additionally port 123 (TCP/UDP) has to be open to set the time automatically.

This is a list of all ports for Apple-related protocols, in case there are any remaining issues - [Apple KB: TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944)